# Could not load config file solrconfig.xml

Tags: tomcat, solr, debian

I am very new in debian and I just install the solr on debian server. but I am getting the following error:-

```
    core1: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file /usr/share/solr/live/solr/core1/solrconfig.xml
new_core: org.apache.solr.common.SolrException:org.apache.solr.common.SolrException: Could not load config file /usr/share/solr/live/solr/new_core/solrconfig.xml
```

where I can find that file, where and  how to set the path  I Google it and could not found any solution please help me.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Why the `node.js` tag?

Comment: @MattHarrison it was by mistake :)

Comment: @user3819192 see http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/56m8E/7/ for [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24905341/create-json-from-javscript-array-in-javascript)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Well, it's telling you where it expects the file to be found. An example solrconfig.xml is bundled with the source distribution, so you can find [the default example on the Lucene SVN browser](http://svn.apache.org/viewvc/lucene/dev/trunk/solr/server/solr/configsets/basic_configs/conf/solrconfig.xml?view=markup).

Comment: @AlbinGeorge Thanks, I've updated the link to point to the new location in SVN after the files was moved to the 'server' directory.